# routing url rewrite with laravel 4

Tags: php, url, laravel, routes, url-rewriting

I'm using laravel framework since a few weeks now and i'm building a litle website with it.

For now, I have:

1. an index page which display a login form
2. an index/auth page which verify the authentication of the user, but doesn't display any view and redirect the user either on the next page, or the first index page
3. a page that dislay a list of patient if the user logged in

Here is my problem. My authentication works well, but when I'm redirecting the user to the patient list page, the url become "index/auth".

My route file looks like :

```
Route::get('index', array('as'=>'index', 'uses'=>'WUsersController@getIndex'));

Route::post('index/auth', array('uses'=>'WUsersController@postAuth'));

Route::get('patients', array('as'=>'patients', 'uses'=>'PatientsController@getPatientList'));
```

My WUsersController looks like :

```
    public function getIndex() {
    return View::make('wusers.index')
        ->with('title', 'Instant Access');
}

public function postAuth() {
    $rules = array(
            'email'=>'required|email',
            'password'=>'required|alphaNum|min:4'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    $user = WUserModel::where('WUS_EMAIL', '=', Input::get('email'))->first();

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::route('index')
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }
    if ($user->WUS_PASSWORD == md5(Input::get('password'))) {
        Session::put('login', $user->WUS_EMAIL);
            return Redirect::route('patients')
                ->with('title', 'Patient List');
        }   
    return Redirect::route('index')
        ->with('logError', 'login ou mot de passe incorrect');
}
```

this is the "wusers.index" view with the form :

```
@section('content')
<div id="loginPage" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>InstantAccess</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" style="text-align:center">
        {{ HTML::image('img/logo_keosys.png') }}
            {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'index/auth', 'method'=>'POST', 'id'=>'loginForm')) }}

            <p>
                {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                {{ $errors->first('password') }}
            </p>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <p>
                {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:') }}<br />
                {{ Form::text('email') }}
            </p>

            <p>
                {{ Form::label('passorwd', 'Password:') }}<br />
                {{ Form::password('password') }}
            </p>
             </div> 
            <p>{{ Form::submit('Sign in', array('name'=>'login', 'value'=>'Valider')) }}</p>

            @if (Session::has('logError'))
                <p style="color: red;">{{ Session::get('logError') }}</p>
            @endif

            {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
</div>
```

@stop

and this is my PatientsController :

```
    public function getPatientList() {
        return View::make('patients.index', array(
            'title'=>'Patients List',
            'patients'=>DB::table('patient')
                ->join('study', 'patient.pat_id', '=', 'study.sty_pat_id')
                ->select('patient.pat_id', 'patient.pat_name', 'patient.pat_nip', 'patient.pat_birthdate', 'patient.pat_sex', 'study.sty_description', 'study.sty_datetime')
                ->orderBy('study.sty_datetime', 'desc')->take(10)->get())
            );
}
```

It's been 2 weeks I'm on that problem now, I cannot continue to work on my website till this problem is solved.

If you have any question, don't hesitate, and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the postAuth method is your issue for the following reasons:

- You seem to be getting out two user arrays from your model every login
- One array is with email addresses that equal the one you entered, Isn't this unique? If so you could just get the first record rather than all of them
- The other array is an array of users with the same password. This seems like very bad practice.

Instead what you should be doing is getting out a unique user object via the email address and checking if its password matches the one provided and redirecting accordingly

```
public function postAuth() {
    $rules = array(
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'password'=>'required|alphaNum|min:4'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // Early dropout if we have an invalid email
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::route('index')
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $user = WUserModel::where('WUS_EMAIL', '=', Input::get('email'))->first();
    if($user->WUS_PASSWORD == md5(Input::get('password'))) {
        Session::put('login', $user->WUS_EMAIL);
        return Redirect::to('patients')
            ->with('title', 'Patient List');**
    }

    return Redirect::route('index')
        ->with('logError', 'login ou mot de passe incorrect');
}
```

As a side point Laravel has Authentication built in so you could just use that. And you probably want to be using something stronger than MD5 for passwords.

Comment: Thank you for that optimisation, my authentication still works (and looks better). I know it's not very good practice, and I know there is the Auth method I can use with laravel, but I have a specific database which is used in production and doesn't match the laravel driver tables names ... (i'm working on it)

So I changed with what you provided, but the url stay unchanged to "index/auth" instead of "patients" after redirecting the user.

Comment: From the code, it looks like it should work add some debugging where you are setting the session when the user has logged in correctly. If that works and gets output correctly, add some logging to the action in your patients controller to see if that gets output.

Comment: Well, I can tell you it works, if I use correct email and password, I'm redirect to the patients page, but the url is "index/auth" instead of "patients". But it works. And for example, if I provide wrong information when I'm logging in, I'm staying on the form page, but the url is "index/auth" instead of "index".

Answer (score 0):

As I was testing things to find out what was my mistake, I realized that, on my index page which display the form, I have two links to "includes" jquery and jquery-mobile.

it looks like:

```
@section('header')
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>

    {{ HTML::style('css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js') }}

@stop
```

So, when I remove one of those two .js links, I lose the graphical aspect of my form, but the url is rewrite properly...

I don't get it, but the problem seems to come from those .js file.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. It was because of ajax queries. It loads the content of the page on this same page to avoid the refresh, and so it would do that after my authentication, that's why the url stayed unchange to "index/auth" instead of "patients". Thanks for your help